# How to inherit from another view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to make a simple website where user can order someting to eat.
So I've got a view with lots of methods - 'pizza_sizes' is only one of them:

```
class PizzaOrderView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pizza/pizza_order.html'
    pizza_type = ProductType.objects.filter(name='Regular Pizza').values_list('id', flat=True)[0]

    def post(self, request):
        to_return = add_to_cart(request)
        return to_return

    def pizza_sizes(self):
        sizes = Product.objects.filter(type=self.pizza_type).values_list('size__name', flat=True).distinct()
        return sizes
```

I also have a ListView displaying all products that user has in cart.

```
class CartView(ListView):
    template_name = 'orders/cart.html'
```

From this page user can either delete or update product. So I am using UpdateView to let him update it, but then again I need all those methods (that I use in PizzaOrderView). I could rewrite those methods to this view, but it doesn't make much sens, I tried to inherit it like this:

```
class ProductUpdateView(UpdateView, PizzaOrderView):
    model = CartItem
    fields = '__all__'
    pizza_type = list(ProductType.objects.filter(name__contains='Pizza').values_list('id', flat=True))

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        cart_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        to_return = update_user_cart(request, cart_id)
        return to_return

    def get_template_names(self):
        product_type = CartItem.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs.get('pk')).values_list('product__type', flat=True)[0]
        if product_type in self.pizza_type:
            self.template_name_suffix = '_pizza_update'
        else:
            self.template_name_suffix = '_form'
        return super().get_template_names()
```

And then use it in my template, but then it throws an AttributeError:

> 'ProductUpdateView' object has no attribute 'object'

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\jakub.sygowski\Documents\django\CS50\project3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\jakub.sygowski\Documents\django\CS50\project3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\jakub.sygowski\Documents\django\CS50\project3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\jakub.sygowski\Documents\django\CS50\project3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\jakub.sygowski\Documents\django\CS50\project3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\jakub.sygowski\Documents\django\CS50\project3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in get
  158.         context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\jakub.sygowski\Documents\django\CS50\project3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_context_data
  67.         return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\jakub.sygowski\Documents\django\CS50\project3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py" in get_context_data
  94.         if self.object:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /update/47 Exception Value: 'ProductUpdateView' object has no attribute 'object'
```

As if it somehow lost its 'object' property from ListView.

What am I missing here? What is a proper way to do it?

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: Sure, I already edited question

Comment: Look at [this](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/) to understand the various methods of `UpdateView` and `TemplateView`. Are you sure you inherit from `UpdateView` first and not `PizzaOrderView` first? (it looks like the `get()` method from the `TemplateView` is called instead of the one from the `UpdateView`). One problem I see is that you're inheriting multiple classes twice so I would advise you to create a mixin class instead (that does not subclass a generic Django `View`) with your methods and in both views inherit from your mixin class.

Comment: Also, don't just override `post()` in your `UpdateView` like this. This removes all the functionality your get from using a generic class-based view. You probably want to do this in `form_valid()` but it's not clear what `update_user_cart` does so I can't tell. Again, the link in my previous comment is your friend.